# Posting an array to/thru ajax to php

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

So I have an array that gets created from a php loop that looks like this:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" id="types[]" value="' . $id . '"> ' . $type . '<br>';
```

And while it works just passing it to php, I wanted to do some updates and pass it to ajax
to pass to php so I can have the ajax do a fancy return on the page for me.

I've tried all types of ways to get it to pass to the ajax and over to php, but nothing works.

Here is the ajax code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#contactform').submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
        $('#message').hide();

        $('#submit')
            .after('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
            .attr('disabled','disabled');



        $.post(action, {
            types['types[]']: $('#types').val(),
            form_name: $('#form_name').val(),
            site_id: $('#site_id').val()
        },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

            }
        );

        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

Im trying to get this to work as well because the rest of the site uses the same functionality, and I would like to keep this the same way. I wouldn't want to have to take
out the other ajax stuff on pages already created.

So any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

### Edit/Update:

So after setting the line like Meager explained:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" class="types" value="' . $id . '"> ' . $type . '<br>';
```

And adjusting the ajax code to this:

```
    $.post(action, {
        form_name: $('#form_name').val(),
        site_id: $('#site_id').val(),
        types: $('.types').map(function(){ $(this).val(); });

    },
```

It just seems to be bypassing the ajax and posting right over to my process.php file with:

```
Array
(
    [types] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 21
            [2] => 22
        )

    [site_id] => 112
    [form_name] => prd_svc
    [Submit] => Submit
)
```

==========================================

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message').hide();

    $('#submit')
        .after('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');



    $.post(action, {
        form_name: $('#form_name').val(),
        site_id: $('#site_id').val(),
        types: $('.types').map(function(){ $(this).val(); });

    },
        function(data){
            $('#message').html(data);
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

        }
    );

    });

    return false;

});

});
```

Comment: Is the problem that `$('#types')` isn't passing anything?  I think you might want `$('#types\[\]')` instead.

Comment: When I look at the developer tools using Chrome, this is what I see getting passed in the post:

types[]:20
types[]:21
types[]:22
site_id:112
form_name:prd_svc

Comment: And another reason I know it's not correct, because if it was, then it would be doing the ajax slideup function, and it's not - its just posting straight thru to my process.php file which handles it

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, you should *use jQuery*. `document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;` should be `$('#message').html(data)`.

Comment: @SenorAmor That won't help. You can't use `types[]` as an ID and expect it to turn the elements into an array. That isn't supported by jQuery or the underlying DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt to create an "array" of elements via this: `id="types[]"` is wrong. You can't group elements this way, and if you could, this still wouldn't return an array of values: `$('#types').val()`.

You'll have to assign each element a unique ID, or give them all a shared class and select by that:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" class="types" value="' . $id . '"> ' . $type . '<br>';
```

Then, to turn an set of elements selected into their values, you can use `map`:

```
// Collect all values
$('.types').map(function () { $(this).val(); });
```

Comment: Meagar,

 Does that mean it will collect 'all' values and pass them or just the types? I think types but I want to clarify. Im a fantastic programmer, just not so good with ajax stuff

Comment: It will collect all the values for every element that has `class="types"`. And your problem has nothing to do with AJAX, you're just building an invalid DOM document with broken ID attributes on your `<input>`s. The ID has to be unique across the document.

Comment: I already have the post action set and catching other variables. I know this is probably wrong and forgive my ignorance but:

 $.post(action, {
  form_name: $('#form_name').val(),
  site_id: $('#site_id').val(),
  types: $('#types').map(function () { $(this).val(); })

 },

Comment: `.types`, not `#types`. You should read up on [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) so you know what you're doing, rather than fumbling around.

Comment: and it's correct to set it with types: $('.types').map(function() $(this).val(); })}? Because it just seems to be crashing the page.

Comment: apparently i am not going to be able to get this right, and just have to tear it down because of a stupid array that wont pass correctly.

Comment: It only does what you tell it. Calling your tools "stupid" is childish. Your own ignorance is the problem. Spend some time learning what you're doing instead of trying to cobble things together.